# How can I use glfwSetWindowUserPointer in LWJGL 3?

Tags: java, game-engine, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a Window class to abstract all the GLFW stuff. The thing is that I don't know how to use glfwSetWindowUserPointer in LWJGL.

I've used the function before, but in C++. Now I'm moving to Java, using LWJGL.

In C++, I would do something like:

```cpp
    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(myWindow, &myData)
```

But in LWJGL the function takes 2 `long`, where the first argument is the window handle, but I don't know what to do with the second one.

How can I pass a pointer to my object containing all the data I need inside the callbacks?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at `JNINativeInterface.New/DeleteGlobalRef`and `memGlobalRefToObject`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on [@elect](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1047713/elect)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264393/how-can-i-use-glfwsetwindowuserpointer-in-lwjgl-3#comment99154704_56264393) about `JNINativeInterface` and `memGlobalRefToObject`:

```
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil;
import org.lwjgl.system.jni.JNINativeInterface;

class JavaObject {
    String message;

    JavaObject(String message) {
        this.message = message
    }
}

final long pointer = JNINativeInterface.NewGlobalRef(new JavaObject("Hello"));
JavaObject object = MemoryUtil.memGlobalRefToObject(pointer);
JNINativeInterface.DeleteGlobalRef(pointer);

System.out.println(object.message) // => "Hello"

// Already deleted the strong reference held by the native part of the application.
object = MemoryUtil.memGlobalRefToObject(pointer);
System.out.println(object) // => null
```

On a bit of advice: I'd only use the GLFW user pointer for the callbacks set with `glfwSetMonitorCallback` and `glfwSetErrorCallback`. You don't need it for the window callbacks, as you set one callback per window, so you already have a reference to each Java wrapper class.

```
class Window {
    final long handle;

    int width;
    int height;

    WindowObserver observer;

    Window(final long handle, final int width, final int height) {
        this.handle = handle;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(handle, (handle, w, h) -> {
            if (observer != null) {
                observer.windowDidResize(this, this.width, this.height, w, h);
            }

            this.width = w;
            this.height = h;
        });
    }
}
```